# Binding the same variable more than once for mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a site in which I need to rewrite all the SQL to be prepared statements in the MySQLi Prepared format.

Similar to the below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE Job_Id = ?"; 

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);

// Bind parameters
$stmt->bind_param('i', $Job_Id);

// Execute statement
$stmt->execute();

// Bind result
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows >= 1){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    }
}
```

I came across this line:

`UPDATE jobs SET jobTitle = IF('$jobTitle' = '', jobTitle, '$jobTitle'),`

How would this query line be represented in a prepared statement? Surely all the variables would be replaced with ?, but then do I have to re-use the same variable and have more placeholders?

Comment: Why not just call your update ONLY if the new job title is not empty?

Comment: Yes, you would replace your variables with ? and use more placeholders and re-use the same variable

Comment: So in a scenario where I had a form of say, 5 fields I could just do an update and if they aren't changed it would just insert the same data?

Comment: If the value of those 5 fields are set from the data with the same ID as the table you are updating and they havn't changed, MySQL will still execute and replace the text regardless. Hope this makes sense